# PostgreSQL query does not use index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.the_table
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('the_table_id_seq'::regclass),
  report_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  value_id integer NOT NULL,
  text_value character varying(255),
  numeric_value double precision,
  bool_value boolean,
  dt_value timestamp with time zone,
  exported boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT the_table_fkey_valdef FOREIGN KEY (value_id)
      REFERENCES public.value_defs (value_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.the_table
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Indices:

```
CREATE INDEX the_table_idx_id ON public.the_table USING brin (id);
CREATE INDEX the_table_idx_timestamp ON public.the_table USING btree (report_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX the_table_idx_tsvid ON public.the_table USING brin (report_timestamp, value_id);
CREATE INDEX the_table_idx_valueid ON public.the_table USING btree (value_id);
```

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table r WHERE r.value_id = 1064 ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1;
```

While running the query PostgreSQL does not use `the_table_idx_valueid` index.

Why?

Comment: Actually the `the_table_idx_valueid` index is the one I would have expected as the most likely to be used.  Keep in mind that you are doing a `select *`, and none of your four indices are covering this, so Postgres might choose to just scan the table.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: I thought my entire life, that indices cover `WHERE`, but not the fields to be outputted.

Comment: The thing is, if you only cover `WHERE` then when Postgres reaches the leaf node for that record, it then has to do a disk seek to the actual table to retrieve the values for select.  Checkout the answer below as it might be better than what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, this index will help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON the_table (value_id, report_timestamp);
```

Depending on the selectivity of the condition and the number of rows in the table, PostgreSQL may correctly deduce that a sequential scan and a sort is faster than an index scan.

Comment: I understand! When I omit `ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc` the index `the_table_idx_valueid` is used. Thank you.